# Android development: convert gif-File to video

Tags: java, android, video, converters, gif

I'm currently developing an android app, that converts normal gif-files to videos. But after some research I didn't find any good examples or hints. I've seen some existing apps, that have that functionality, so I'm sure there is a way, but in my opinion the most apps are inconsistent and buggy. Does anyone have an example, how it's done?

Regards
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ACT_GIF_MOV extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setView();
    }
    void setView()
    {
        InputStream stream = null; 
        try { 
            stream = getAssets().open("animation.gif"); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 

        } 
        GifMovieView view = new GifMovieView(this, stream); 
        setContentView(view); 
    }
    class GifMovieView extends View
    {
        private Movie mMovie;     
        InputStream mStream;
        long mMoviestart=0;
        public GifMovieView(Context context, InputStream stream) 
        {         
            super(context);        
            mStream = stream;         
            mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mStream);             
        } 
        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        { 
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
            super.onDraw(canvas); 
            final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); 
            if (mMoviestart == 0) { mMoviestart = now; } 
            final int relTime = (int)((now - mMoviestart) % mMovie.duration()); mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10); this.invalidate(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Eu.Dr.
Tanks for the tipp. I already implemented that, but how can I save the Movie object in the internal storage?